# Proof $G$ has a unique normal subgroup $H$ of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. $G$ is the group of functions $f(x)=ax+b$ from $\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}\Z/p\Z$ to $\Z/p\Z$ where $a$ belongs to $(\Z/p\Z)*$ and $b$ belongs to $(\Z/p\Z)$.

I proved that $G$ is a group under the composition of functions.

I'm asked to prove now that $G$ has a *unique* normal subgroup of order $p$ and I have to confess that I'm stucked on this one.

I found the cardinality of $G$ to be equal to $p^2-p$ and then tried to use conjugacy classes to show that this was the only option but I didn't find anything convincing (I migh have done it wrongly).

Could anyone help me, with the conjugacy classes or even with something completely different. I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Consider what an element must look like to have order $p$. Or, alternatively, show that it has a normal subgroup of order $p$ (one can find it explicitly), and apply the Sylow theorems.

Comment: I'm not sure I see your point... If an element has order p, all I can think of is the fact that it'll generate a subgoup of order p too... It's probably obvious for you but would you mind elaborating just a bit more ? Thanks

Comment: You have the group given explicitly, consider what happens when you compose a function with itself $p$ times. For what values of $a$ and $b$ will that composition be the identity?

Comment: If a=1 and b=0 ?

Comment: That is one example, but that one is already the identity.

Comment: Aaaaah, ok ok I wasn't thinking the right way I guess. I get it now ! Thanks for your time.